# SQLAlchemy Find a user with a single query (probably join necessary)

Tags: sql, join, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have three models which have relationships.

Firstly, the participant model.

```
class Participant(UserMixin, db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'participants'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
email = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teams.id'))

# Relationships
team = db.relationship("Team", back_populates="members")
```

Secondly, the event model.

```
class Event(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'events'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Thirdly, the team model.

```
class Team(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'teams'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
event_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('events.id'))

# Relationships
members = db.relationship('Participant', back_populates="team")
```

Several participants are allowed to have the same email address if their team is not connected to the same event.

I am looking for a query which checks if there is a participant with a given email address who is connected to a team, which is connected to the same event. I know  the event.id and the email address in advance.

Pseudo code

```
def check(EVENTID, EMAIL):
    if db.session.query(Team, Event, Participant). \
        filter(Team.event_id == EVENTID). \
        filter(Participant.team_id == Team.id). \ 
        filter(Participant.email == EMAIL).first():
        return true
```

I think it can be done with one single query using joins, but I couldn't figure it out. Please help!

Comment: You're already doing a single query with joins. What are you actually having trouble with?

Comment: This is only pseudo code. It doesn't work. I always get None as a result.

Comment: Other than the fact that `Event` doesn't need to be in the `FROM` list, there's nothing wrong with your query. Are you sure you have a row that matches that condition?